# ASP.NET MVC3 - user permissions and access

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I'm quite new to user control in .NET and need a bit of help.

I'm building an application that is blog-based, where each user can have multiple blogs within the application.
I need a way of allowing permission to these blogs and storing the list of allowed blogs on the user model. I'll also need to verify that the user has access then by checking the list/collection.

I've defined classes for the Blogs and I'm using built-in Membership so far.
Any suggestions are welcome :)

Using MVC3 and Entity Framework.

Cheers
Scott

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you would be better served by storing the allowed users on the blogs, rather than the allowed blogs on the user.

Then you need only check the users user id against the blogs allowed user id's.

This has the advantage that if you delete a blog, you don't need to update the user to remove blog access.  Sort of like the difference between having a bouncer at the door that stops someone from entering if they are not on a list.  Should the bouncer have the list of people authorized?  Or should the patron have a list of clubs he's allowed to go to? It's just logically a better choice.